# Adding certain json objects to a new JSON array converts decimals to strings

Tags: java, json, jackson

So I have this method that is being used to remove particular JSON objects from a JSON Array by taking in an input array and an index to remove as parameters. What is happening is that decimal values are being converted from their original decimal values to strings. Is there any reason for this behavior and how i can prevent it?

Expected vs real output example:

```
Expected output: 
[{
   "temperature" : 12.4303249 
}]

Real output: 
[{
   "temperature" : "12.4303249"
}]
```

Method Written

```
public ArrayNode removeJsonObject(ArrayNode inputArray, int position){
   ArrayNode jsonArray = new ObjectMapper().createArrayNode();     
   int len = inputArray.size();
   for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
   { 
       //Excluding the item at position
        if (i != position) 
        {
            jsonArray.add(inputArray.get(i));
        }
    }
   return jsonArray
}
```

I ideally would've expected decimal values to remain as decimal values, however they were converted to strings. I have tried passing ints, strings, and booleans which all maintain the same data type.